# In C#, how to delete "Explorer file associate" overriding the "Registry Classes" File Association?

Tags: c#, registry, file-association

How to programatically delete all "file association" created by Explorer so that the file associations under HKCR work correctly?

For Example, I want to delete the registry key corresponding a user clicking "open with..." in explorer. Example:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt
```

or other file extension such as .py or .pl.

I wrote some c# code to do this... however it throws an exception.  Here's What I'm trying to do:

```
    ExplorerOverrideDelete(".txt");

    // Throws Exception:
    //  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Cannot write to the registry key.
```

Here's the Functions:

```
    public static void ExplorerOverrideDelete (string ext)
    {
        if (!ext.StartsWith(".")) {
            ext = "." + ext;
        }

        var hivereg = GetHive("HKCU");

        var key     = hivereg.OpenSubKey(
            @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\"
                       + ext);
        if (key == null)
            return;

        var keyroot     = hivereg.OpenSubKey(
            @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts");

        if (keyroot == null)
            return;

        keyroot.DeleteSubKeyTree(ext);

        key.Dispose();
        keyroot.Dispose();
        hivereg.Dispose();
    }

    private static RegistryKey GetHive(string hive) {
        switch(hive.ToUpper()) {
            case "HKCU": return Registry.CurrentUser;
            case "HKLM": return Registry.LocalMachine;
            case "HKCR": return Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Some more Information:

```
PS C:\Users\john\Documents> get-acl HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts | fl


Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileE
         xts
Owner  : DESKTOP-D3USQOT\john
Group  : DESKTOP-D3USQOT\None
Access : DESKTOP-D3USQOT\john Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\RESTRICTED Allow  ReadKey
         APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES Allow  R

PS C:\Users\john\Documents> get-acl HKCU:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt | fl

Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileE
         xts\.txt
Owner  : DESKTOP-D3USQOT\john
Group  : DESKTOP-D3USQOT\None
Access : DESKTOP-D3USQOT\john Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         NT AUTHORITY\RESTRICTED Allow  ReadKey
         APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES
```

Comment: "UnauthorizedAccessException" is pretty clear. Try running your program as administrator.

Comment: My understanding is that you don't need administrator to modify HKCU.  HKLM is the hive that requires Admin privilege.  Also, I tried it already.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that works for me.  I still don't entirely understand why I need to run this as Admin since the ACL for current user has full-control.  If anybody has any idea about that, give me a shout below. Thanks.

```
public static void ExplorerOverrideDelete (string ext)
{
    if (!IsAdministrator()) {
        MessageBox.Show(
            "ExplorerOverrideDelete(): Rerun program as Admin",
            "Access Denied"
    }

    if (!ext.StartsWith(".")) {
        ext = "." + ext;
    }

    var keyroot     = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
        @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts", 
        RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

    if (keyroot == null)
        return;

    keyroot.GetAccessControl(System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.All);

    // /keyroot.GetAccessControl(
    //     System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.All
    //  & ~System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.Audit);

    try {
        keyroot.DeleteSubKeyTree(ext);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        keyroot.Close();
        hivereg.Close();            
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

    keyroot.Close();
    hivereg.Close();
}

public static bool IsAdministrator()
{
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity
        = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal principal
        = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    return principal.IsInRole(
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator
    );
}
```